# Tasks are not go queue from web page

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using CRM-2011 and create task from asp.net webpage after create task put in specific queue. all working fine but some time task is create but it is not goes in any queue.
It happened some time but create lots of problem.

if any one have any idea about this please share with me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing any error logging? It could be that a web service call fails every now and then. We are talking about networks and they do fail sometimes...

To mitigate this you could consider using [Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481600.aspx) in CRM 2013-2015. They are built for these very scenarios. If you indeed are running CRM 2011 (and don't have plans to upgrade) then you could consider making a "Web Task"-entity in which you collect all the information (task info and queue) and then in a plugin do the creation of the task and assignment to the queue in one transaction scope.